# Remove possible null warning of nulleable v

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq query where I map some models as:

```
return campaigns
            .Select(
                c =>
                    new CampaignSelectViewModel
                    {
                        CampaignId = c.CampaignId,
                        CampaignName = c.Name,
                        ..
                        CampaignStations = c.CampaignStations
                            .Select(cs => cs.Station)
                            .Select(
                                s =>
                                    new StationSelectViewModel
                                    {
                                        StationId = s.StationId,
                                        ...
                                    }
                            )
                            .ToList()
                    }
            )
            .ToList();
```

The IDE marks the `s` as possible `null` because `Station` on campaign station can be null, so I want to validate it if station is not null then assign the `StationSelectModel`, how can I achieve that?:

Comment: `.Where(cs => cs.Station != null).Select(cs => cs.Station)....`

Comment: This does not fix the problem, just continue showing possible null reference @MetroSmurf

Comment: If the "problem" is a nullable compiler warning, then it's not a problem. The where clause already filters out the null items. The warning is due to your project being defined with `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>`. To suppress the warning, use the [! (null-forgiving) operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving). `.Where(cs => cs.Station != null).Select(cs => cs.Station!)...`

Comment: `.Select(cs => cs.Station!)`

Comment: `StationId = s?.StationId ?? defaultID,` if you want to assign some `defaultID` when `s` is `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return something when it is null, then

```
return campaigns
            .Select(
                c =>
                    new CampaignSelectViewModel
                    {
                        CampaignId = c.CampaignId,
                        CampaignName = c.Name,
                        ..
                        CampaignStations = c.CampaignStations
                            .Select(cs => cs.Station)
                            .Select(
                                s =>
                                {
                                    if (s != null)
                                    {
                                        return new StationSelectViewModel
                                        {
                                            StationId = s.StationId,
                                            ...
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        return new StationSelectViewModel
                                        {
                                            StationId = SOMETHING ELSE
                                            ...
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            )
                            .ToList()
                    }
            )
            .ToList();
```

Comment: What if I don't want to send nothing if its null? I mean I just want the object empty, it should be  only    `return new StationSelectViewModel();` instead else right?

Comment: @Demian - check my comment to your post; it does exactly that.